# Why not just use a static variable as reference count for smart pointer

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

When I check out the "enhanced" version smart pointer - enhancement is to have reference counting added - I see they use some "complex" techniques for the ref count, e.g. a totally seperate class or a pointer pointing to an integer.

Here is one example:

```
template<class T>
class SmartPointer{
  T* mp_T;
  unsigned int * mp_Count;
  public:
    ... all the APIs ...
};
```

I am wondering, what is the gain? Since the goal is to have all the instances sharing the value, why not just declaring it as an static member variable:

```
template<class T>
class SmartPointer{
  T* mp_T;
  static unsigned int m_Count;
  public:
    ... all the APIs ...
};
```

I must miss something, but after some searching, I cannot find any answer. Please shed some light.

Comment: "Since the goal is to have all the instances sharing the value"

It's not.

Answer (score 13):

A static data member is shared by all instances *of the same class*. But two distinct smart pointers should not share the same reference count. Take an example,

```
SmartPointer<int> a;
...
SmartPointer<int> b;
SmartPointer<int> c = b;   // ref count increased due to copying.
```

In your scheme, `a`'s `m_Count` will be increased as well in the commented line, because the `static` variable is shared among all `SmartPointer<int>`, although this line is irrelevant to `a`.

Answer (score 7):

The idea is not "to have all the instances share the value". What made you think so?

The idea is to have *all pointer instances that point to the same object* to share the counter. And pointer instances that point to different objects should have independent non-shared counters. The static counter will not implement this concept.

Answer (score 3):

The goal is not to have all instances of a `SmartPointer<T>` sharing a single value for the entire process.  Instead the goal is for several instances of `SmartPointer<T>` to be sharing a single value.  There may be multiple instances of `T*` for which several smart pointers share a value.  For example

```
SmartPointer<MyType> sp1 = new MyType();
SmartPointer<MyType> sp2 = new MyType();
```

Having a static counter here would incorrectly tie the lifetime of two completely independent `MyType` values together.

Answer (score 1):

**In a typical use case, there would be multiple objects**, with one or more shared pointers pointing to each object.

Using a `static` reference count would not permit having multiple objects, since there will only be one reference count.

Answer (score 0):

If a static variable is defined in a class that means this variable is shared among all objects of that class, irrespective of whether all objects are linked or not.

```
shared_ptr<int> sp1(new int);
shared_ptr<int> sp2(sp1);
```

Here, `sp1` & `sp2` will have a refCount = 2, because `sp1` and `sp2` are linked.

```
shared_ptr<int> sp3(new int);
```

If refCount were static, then the refCount of `sp3` would have been `3`.
The expected value of `sp3`'s refCount is `1` because `sp3` is not linked to neither `sp1` nor `sp2`.